# Can the GitHub Atom editor show properties and functions of classes?

Tags: atom-editor

Recently I moved from NetBeans to GitHub Atom editor. How can I access properties and functions of classes in the editor?

Answer (score 2):

I use a mix with the [symbol gen](https://atom.io/packages/symbol-gen) and [symbols view packages](https://atom.io/packages/symbols-view). First one very good about generating ctag file for your project and second one for inspect code and jump to the definitions of tags. Also, it supports `Show all symbols in current file` future. It have to show for you the members and properties of your classes.

In short: after installation open a work directory with your project and try `alt + cmd + g`, wait several seconds, ctags file generating now for you and after that `cmd + r` and just start typing any part of a method or property in the input.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the previous answers, I would recommend you to check Atom's package [goto-definition](https://atom.io/packages/goto-definition), with its optional "performance mode" (which requires you to install [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep#installation)).

goto-definition will allow you to find and access properties and 
functions/classes definitions even if they are not written in the same file. In combination with ripgrep, goto-definition is extremely fast, and you will not have to wait for file indexing within your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the members of a Java class (which I assume, since you've used NetBeans before), then this is currently not supported in Atom.

Atom is a (fairly simple) editor that allows you to edit text files, while full-blown IDEs (Integrated Development Environments) like *Eclipse*, *NetBeans* or *IntelliJ IDEA* have full language support including running, debugging and browsing Java class information. It might be better to stick with one of the IDEs I mentioned if you are looking for this kind of functionality.

Having said that, there's the https://atom.io/packages/atom-ctags package, which supposedly can show some meta information about classes you're working on. It's primarily for C++, although it might work for Java as well (I haven't tried).